# Getting a Bash related issue when compiling typescript code

Tags: typescript

*I don't know if this can even be asked here, but, here goes:*

I've just installed Ubuntu 19.03 as my second bootable OS, and I installed VSC, git, nodejs, etc. I have installed typescript, and it works for my other projects, but when I try to compile one of my old projects (also written in TS), I get a weird bash-related error in the console.

```sh
> Executing task: tsc -p '/media/kennysinner/When You Fuck Up/Bots/Ja'far Bot/tsconfig.json' <

/bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

*Please do note that I did use the integrated compiler task 'tsc: build' that runs my `tsconfig.json`*

This is what my `tsconfig.json` compiler options consists of:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "target": "es2017",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "inlineSourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "src/bot/javascript/"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/bot/typescript/", 
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I have done some google searching and I cannot find the answer to my issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, special thank you to discord user `veksen#1060` who answered my question in a matter of seconds. 
The issue was that my namespace had a `'` inside of it so the compiler messed up with getting the dir/ (I suppose, I am not a 100% certain if that's why it didn't work, all I do know it's because of the `'` inside of my project's name.)